# Any easy way to generate a build script from an H2 database?

Tags: database-replication, h2, sql-scripts

let's image that one creates an H2 database with table, indexes, etc... Is there an easy way to extract a SQL script to recreate the structure of this database in another H2 database?

I am not referring to the content of the tables, indexes, etc... I am just interested in the general structure of the database to replicate it elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would use [`SCRIPT NODATA`](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#script) (returns a result set) or `SCRIPT NODATA TO 'fileName'`.

Comment: How did I missed that...? Thanks!